# calculating nine patch sizes for all densities

Tags: android, nine-patch, density-independent-pixel

I dont know how is best way to calculate size in pixels for round corners in nine patch images in all folders (hdpi, mdpi...), if I want for example 5dp round corner or something close to this size on all devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

A quick summary is

```
ldpi (0.75 x mdpi)
 |
mdpi (basline)
 |
hdpi (1.5 x mdpi)
 |
xhdpi (2.0 x mdpi)
```

And also, remember that Android will scale the images, so if you set the corner as 5dp. It *will* be 5dp on all devices. Different res images are used to make sure it dosent look low quality on a higher density screen.

So in your case, create a 5px image (mdpi one) then scale it to other densities using the metrics shown above.